# How to insert and push data from xlsm file to sql?

Tags: python, sql, excel, pandas

I have an xlsm workbook which contains tables and charts in every sheet I want now to import and push my xlsm data to any sql
I searched how to do this I find the best way to push the data is by python and pandas but I didn't figured out till now
So is there's any way to insert all my data to sql to be easily work with and automate my data
And if there's some tutorial for this please just let me know or how can I do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you need to install the requirements:

1. pip install mysqlclient
2. pip install pandas
3. Install xampp for web server with MySQL Database
4. Install MS Excel to make the table that you want to insert to MySQL DB

This is my PHPMyAdmin database and table name:

[image]

My Excel xlsm workbook:

[image]

After you satisfy the requirements, you can try the following code (don't forget to put python script and xlsm file in the same directory):

```
import pandas as pd, os, MySQLdb

# Your directory
mydir = (os.getcwd()).replace('\\','/') + '/'

df=pd.read_excel(r''+ mydir +'Book1.xlsm')
print(df)

# Establish a MySQL connection
database = MySQLdb.connect (host="127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "", db = "myDB")
print(database)
# Get the cursor, which is used to traverse the database, line by line
cursor = database.cursor()

# Create the INSERT INTO sql query
query = """INSERT INTO myTable (name, email) VALUES ( %s, %s)"""

for i in range(len(df)):
    name=df['name'][i]
    email=df['email'][i]

    # Assign values from each row
    values=(name, email)
    # Execute sql Query
    cursor.execute(query, values)

# Close the cursor
cursor.close()

# Commit the transaction
database.commit()

# Close the database connection
database.close()
print('Insert success!')
```

Output:

```
     name                email
0  alfafa  miftahf77@gmail.com
<_mysql.connection open to '127.0.0.1' at 000002A5CB0BCEA8>
Insert success!
>>>
```

After python script is executed, myTable is changed to be:

[image]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: thanks a lot I will try this and I will give you the feedback